# jQuery FormData - how to set character encoding?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, encoding, utf-8

I have a web application that uses the `FormData` object to upload a over `jQuery.ajax()`. So far so good. The data is sent as a `multipart/form-data` and the server parses it, no problem.

But when I try sending other data along with the file on the same request, I run into a character encoding issue.

My "other data" is in hebrew, so I need the encoding to be `utf-8`.

When I define the ajax option `contentType=false`, google chrome automatically sets the content type request header to be `multipart/form-data; boundary=----webkitwhatever`.
But when I set the ajax option `contentType="multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8"` then google chrome doesn't add the boundary header and the server can't parse the request. But I think it's wrong anyway because even when I set the `charset=utf-8`, I still see the data encoded as gibberish when I look at the request in chrome's dev tools in the Network tab.

How can I fix this?
To be clear, I want to be able to send an ajax request with a file-upload and other data simultaneously, and be able to set the charset encoding to `utf-8` to support hebrew.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this the wrong way entirely.  Do not try to change the Content-Type of a MPE request to something else.  Also, do not expect the data that appears in the dev tools console to reflect the properly decoded values.  For example, if you are on a Mac, the tool you are using to inspect the form data is likely defaulting to Mac's default character encoding of Mac OS Roman.  This does not necessarily indicate a problem with the actual form data character encoding.

All you need to do is set the encoding of your page properly:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

If you do this, the form data will be UTF-8 encoded.  You must decode it properly server-side.